# Common transhuman enhancements

Tags: technology, trans-humanism

Assume a transhuman world where body modification, gene splicing, nanotechnology, biological-technological interfaces, brain emulations, AI, and basic mind modifications exist.

What augmentations would people commonly have? Not for combat, but for living daily life, non-specialist enhancements. Things that would be common enough that nobody would question them, but they don't need to be universal. They should be just things that you use in your daily life.

People have colonized the solar system, so zero-gravity, radiation, temperature ranges, and other things that space colonists face exist.

The implants are reliable, and are cheap if they don't require considerable modification, and maintain themselves if you have a AI manager implant.

Comment: How affordable are these modifications? How reliable? How much maintenance/update/repair do they need and how often? What's the downside? These are just a few of the factors that determine whether something is going to be common, and they're going to change from individual to individual. I think answers you get are going to be largely opinion-based as a result.

Comment: I love the question....if edited to include on what basis answers will be accepted I think it will survive without closing.

Comment: I submitted a vote to close but this question certainly has potential.  Please update the question as @Frostfyre mentioned.  If you are unsure of how to proceed please visit meta or chat and we can talk through it.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan On what did you base your edit?

Comment: @ArtOfCode I am assuming that OP wants the implants to be reliable. That much seems to me to be pretty obvious.

Comment: Okay, making some edits

Comment: @DJMethaneMan Ok, but affordable? Please do try to avoid adding things to the post that the OP hasn't explicitly stated.

Comment: So many works of fiction to relate to!! Going from physical abilities for manual labor workforce, to security detail personnel to (obviously) armed forces. Any enhanced ability: visual, smell, touch, taste, voice, hearing would probably also be common, for various reasons. Then you'd have entertainment gadgets/apps implants (imagine your ipod or iphone implanted behind your ear) or professional implants (being able to take pictures and upload them to wherever with your eyes for photographers, detectives, journalists etc...)

Answer (score 8):

## Sight:

Many people today have bad sight. The elderly have degraded sight and many young people have limited sight too and require glasses. I would imagine that if these implants were commonly available most people with vision problems would have one to augment their ability to see. It is also possible to add infrared vision and many other cool things to their abilities so many normal people will want them too.

## Smell:

This would have to be a combination of implants in the brain and nose and maybe a replacement of nerves. This will enhance our sense of smell and who wouldn't want that (except maybe the guys of clean the sewers and empty the dumpsters)?

## Hearing:

We already have devices that increase our ability to see and it isn't too far fetched to imagine an actual implant becoming more common, especially for law enforcement and government officials and the elderly.

## Others:

I would imagine mechanical muscles being added to our arms and legs to make us generally more fit. Maybe a 'fat burner' to destroy excess fat or recycle it into muscle and stitch it painlessly to our body. This would sell big as modern society is soooooooooo overblown on our obesity epidemic.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? I see no problems here...

Comment: I'm curious, why the dv?

Comment: This seems like you're just listing the senses and doing a bit of mind dumping on how each will get better...

Comment: @Samuel This is what I answered: "What augmentations would people commonly have?" I was simply stating that the senses that directly effect us the most would be the ones with the most common implants.

Answer (score 7):

Things that would benefit any living person:

1. **Memory upgrade / software** - pretty much anything that is available that increases the brains capacity for recall, storage, analytical speed, visual processing, etc. If people can download knowledge (like the Matrix), people would benefit from that as well. Being able to share memories or images directly would be kind of cool to have if that functionality is cheap.
2. **Physical adaptations** - Strength, speed, Better visual ability, better hearing, (better smelling? probably not for the average person, but maybe), louder or more clear voice and better voice control. As far as "strength" goes, most people would likely have a balance between power and endurance - while some specialists may want to focus more on endurance and others may need that one burst of extreme power.
3. **Quality of life changes** - nanobots that assist in fighting bacteria or viruses inside the body, help restore wounds, repair cells, fight cancer, remove tumors, assist failing organs or even take their place. Help get the most energy as possible from food (and assist in sending signals to the body that you have eaten enough, if you have a weight problem). Instant communication without an outside device. Automatic and available readings for any bodily functions or measurements such as nutrition. Automatic contact of help in cases of emergency. These would be the "most important" things. The things that are completely taken for granted because they are just there and being helpful to improve everyone's life.

Answer (score 6):

**Sex**

I know we'd all like to think better of our species, but what are the most common enhancements people do now?  From Viagra, to "enhancements", to boob jobs, humans want to look good and be better in bed.  Even a lot of muscle work, like taking steroids, is often used to help become more attractive.  I'd be willing to be the most common enhancements will be sex related - improving looks, performance, stamina, etc.

Comment: This is probably the most reliable answer. When all else fails: sex!

Answer (score 4):

**Information**

We live in a world driven by information. Having access to any information, at any time, would be incredibly useful - so I predict someone would invent a brain WiFi connector. You'd have access to the full Internet of information, as long as you had some connection. On that subject...

**Connection**

The Internet is fairly useless to you if you can't connect to it. To that end, I expect someone would also come up with a satellite connection receiver, so you can always be connected.

---

Those are more luxury implants. On the other side, I can see a lot of uses for technologies like this in medicine.

**Nanobots**

With nanotechnology, you can create healing nanobots. Having these circulating in your bloodstream means your chances of dying from injury are suddenly much lower.

---

**Interaction**

I expect a major business sector to spring up here. Implants or devices that allow you to interact better - with your environment, with other people - would be very much in demand.

Answer (score 3):

**The Internet**

The most common electronic devices people use today are mobile phones. People of the future would have immersive and implanted versions of these devices for communication and knowledge retrieval.

Mobile phones are already like an extension of people's minds today because they're so incredibly useful. It's likely that people will always demand to have instant communication, search queries, and entertainment available at all times. Instead of everyone on the subway staring at their phones, now everyone on the space elevator will be staring at a space three feet in front of their faces.

Comment: With a wireless "mind link" to the internet, we'd have to worry about attempts to hack your brain and building a firewall for it.  How would you run antivirus on a human brain?  What would a worm or Trojan Horse do to you?

Comment: Not if it is only just that, a 'link'. An implant allowing you to connect whatever device you are holding (special smart glass or whatever) to the internet. Technically you'd just be serving as a router, making it meaningless to your own body if you do get hacked. Hackers could piggy back other stuff through your implant though, but it still wouldnt be dangerous to you (unless the police arrest you thinking your the one...)

Comment: @Jim2B You'd have to worry about it probably less than you have to worry about it for your phone or your car suddenly hacking your brain.

Comment: @Jim2B What would a worm or Trojan do? Zombies!

Answer (score 3):

**Communication**
The most common would be a built in communication device. A way to keep in contact with other people.

**Information**
A close second is a way to get information. This can either be a mental/visual method, like think your question and the information displays in your vision, or something Siri/Cortana like, where you ask a question and hear a response. Probably both will be used.

**Memory**
Everyone wants a better memory, so some kind of co-processor for your brain with memory stores would be very useful.
This could have a second use; personality backup. You're out and about, doing your thing, and get hit by a bus. Killed instantly. So they take you in, extract your backup, grow you a new body in a clone tank, and plug your memory into it. Few days later you're back on your feet. There would be mental side effects, but not being dead gives you a chance to work through those.

**Customization**
People with certain jobs would have different body mod customization's to make their lives easier. As a programmer an extra hand to hold my coffee while using the two hands to type and one to hold the mouse would be very useful.
Wings (a la Birdman) would be useful for paramedics and police officers to get on the scene faster.
Soldiers would probably have weapons grafted in to limbs, armored skin, etc. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P99qJGrPNLs

Answer (score 2):

**Meta enhancments**

**Skeletal upgrades** -Adding musculature has the problem that there is an upper limit to the amount of stress the human skeleton can withstand. Healing nanobots don't necessarily prevent stress fractures, so I propose skeletal enhancements become relatively commonplace. Maybe not Wolverine style unbreakable, but more durable in general.

**Lactic acid management** - Not my idea. But if you can't afford the fake muscles, why not be able to work out without feeling the burn? Turning off this negative feedback does create problems in a few hours of strenuous exercise, but with the right combination of other nanomachinery this is manageable nearly indefinitely.

**Pain management and rehabilitation** - Pain signals are quantifiable, and they can be turned off. As part of the healing modifications, nanotech can detect and isolate pain signals, analyze the root cause of the situation, and start work towards repair and rehabilitation. Fractured tibia? "Oh, my, would you look at that. I'll catch up to you guys in a bit."

**Self-cleaning** - Water is a precious commodity, and hygiene is a must. These both become more important as population density increases. Nanomachinery could be used to handle and discreetly remove excess skin oils and dirt periodically throughout the day and as a mechanical antibiotic that destroys undesirable microbes. Dentistry becomes obsolete, and showers become something you do only in response to a run in the mud.